# How to delete multiple XML elements using one loop?

Tags: python, elementtree

I have some XML data in a file. My code reads it, and I want to remove unwanted elements from it before going on to use the data later in code. I have a list of unwanted names, and I need to remove all nodes at a particular hierarchy position whose attribute `name` is unwanted.

I use a loop `for child_element in parent_element:`, and inside the loop I delete all child elements which match the criteria: `parent_element.remove(child_element)`. The problem is, when it deletes any child, it messes up the iteration, skipping the check for next child element.

To fix this, I added an ugly patch - I run the deleting loop again and again, until it finds nothing to delete.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
...

names_to_delete = ['bad1', 'bad2']
tree = ET.parse(...)
parent_element = tree.getroot()[0][0]
try_delete_name = True
while try_delete_name: # try deleting again and again, until nothing to delete
    try_delete_name = False
    for child_element in parent_element:
        assert 'name' in child_element.attrib
        if child_element.attrib['name'] in names_to_delete:
            parent_element.remove(child_element)
            try_delete_name = True
```

Example XML data:

```
<root>
    <whatever>
        <parent>
            <child name="x">
                <value>99</value>
            </child>
            <child name="bad2">
                <value>222</value>
            </child>
            <child name="y">
                <value>88</value>
            </child>
            <child name="bad1">
                <value>666</value>
            </child>
        </parent>
    </whatever>
</root>
```

How could I implement this using only one pass through the child elements?

Comment: There's something wrong with your XML: where are the closing tags for `child` and the opening tags for `param`?

Comment: With XSLT (available in Pythin's `lxml` module or external processors) you do not need any loop.

Comment: @JackFleeting I posted an edited version of my real XML file; tried to make the names more expressive but forgot to change all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

names_to_delete = ['bad1', 'bad2']
tree = ET.parse("example.xml")
parent_element = tree.getroot()[0][0]

for child in list(parent_element):
    if child.attrib["name"] in names_to_delete:
        parent_element.remove(child)
```

list(parent_elment) returns the children.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to @Christian's answer, another option is with lxml:

```
from lxml import etree

unclean = """[your xml]"""
doc = etree.XML(unclean)

targets = doc.xpath('//parent//child')
for target in targets:
    if target.xpath('./@name')[0] in names_to_delete:
        target.getparent().remove(target)
print(etree.tostring(doc).decode())
```

Output:

```
<root>
    <whatever>
        <parent>
            <child name="x">
                <value>99</value>
            </child>
            <child name="y">
                <value>88</value>
            </child>
            </parent>
    </whatever>
</root>
```